# Queue supporting manual pull of messages in multi-clustered environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an application deployed in GCP which is going to receive certain events from Google Pubsub at any time of the day. The application is going to have a job which is supposed to run every night and process all these events.

Since the processing is not going to happen real-time, I need to store the data from the events until next batch of processing starts. I am considering two ways of storage, either in DB (we are using PostgreSQL) or Any queue (pubsub or any other). The application will be deployed using Kubernetes so there are always going to be multiple nodes of the application.

1)If I decide to store in the database,there is a risk that same row will be picked by more than one nodes. I have seen this issue with MySQL `select for update` with huge data before. Any way to avoid this?

2)If I decide to store in queue, since pubsub events are real-time, whatever node will receive the event will need to hold until the processing starts. In rare cases, if the application needs to be restarted due to some reason, those events will get lost. Is there any other queue that supports manually retrieving messages one by one and the message will be discarded as soon as it is read by one of the nodes (so that it won't be read again by other node )  (something like `BlockingQueue` in java)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Pull subscription with GCP Pubsub also, where we can fetch messages as and when needed and we can also control maximum messages in a batch

Answer (score 0):

1. Kafka holds data, as does Pulsar and Redpanda
2. They don't drop records when consumed, but they dont need to since there are other ways for it to provide exactly once delivery, assuming that's something you want, via transactions and record offset commits
3. If you wanted to use a database as well, you could use tools like Debezium and JDBC Kafka Connector, or Cloud Dataflow to process such Kafka-like events in other ways

Comment: Does Kafka or any other queue support pulling record on demand (only once) instead of delivering it to the client?

Comment: I don't have experience with others. You can easily write Kafka consumer code to poll only once, despite the data still being available in the topic. Alternatively, write data to Postgres and use Debezium to get into Kafka (assuming you need it there) https://debezium.io/blog/2019/02/19/reliable-microservices-data-exchange-with-the-outbox-pattern/